# Android Drawable folder for xperia c3

Tags: android, drawable, sony

Can any one suggest me how to deal with the sony xperia c3 being xhdpi it takes images from drawable-xhdpi but for its screen size (5.6 inch) they seem to be very small. so what should i do now ?

Answer (score 0):

All the images have a scale. This being that their size changes to fit density. Meaning a 200x200 on hdpi will be small on xhdpi. See the launcher icons and see their aspect rates. Make sure the size is big enough for xhdpi

Answer (score -1):

Check folders mini-map (check it in explorer) if you have not smaller images inside.

Comment: do you mean mip-map?